Calculate percentage of different categories on same column in a pivot table
I am trying to analyze some call data over time and date to identify when are calls getting abandoned the most.
My data looks like this:



Id
Date
Time
Abandoned?




123
11/01/2024
09:00 AM
N


456
11/01/2024
10:00 AM
Y


...






And I'd like to have this pivot table, so I can see by hour what percentage of calls are getting abandoned.



Day
9 AM
10 AM
11 AM
12 PM
...




11/01/2024
0%
1%
2%
3%
...


11/02/2024
0%
1%
3%
4%
...



So far I could only get count of abandoned/not abandoned, volume and % of volume over date/time
